# ServicesApiController in referenced project/DLL

Tags: webapi

I'm trying to create some web APIs in a new class library outside of my main website project (still in the same solution). In this library I've added the following API Controller:

```
namespace My.Custom.Namespace
{
    [ServicesController("mycustomnamespace.customapi")]
    public class CustomApi : ServicesApiController
    {
        public HttpResponseMessage TestMethod()
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
        }
    }
}
```

I then add this class library as a reference to my main website project, and try to call the API on this URL:

`http://localhost/sitecore/api/ssc/mycustomnamespace/customapi/1/TestMethod`

But I'm only receiving a `404: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI`

How can I get a `ServicesApiController` to work from a referenced project/DLL?

*Sitecore 8.2 Update 5*

Comment: Why you have /1/ in url? Try removing this and renaming your controller like this "CustomApiController". You are missing the convention to have Controller in the end of name

Comment: @PeterProchazka Because the specification calls for it. Default routing is `/sitecore/api/ssc/{namespace}/{controller}/{id}/{action}` according to http://www.agehrke.com/2015/08/web-api-controller-in-sitecore-8/ I've created and called WebAPIs like this, including the id parameter, from the website project successfully before, but when I follow the same procedure (basically the code in my question) while having the WebAPI in a referenced project/DLL, it doesn't work any more.

Comment: Can you add string id as parameter of your TestMethod and rename CustomApi to CustomApiController?

Comment: Also see comment from your linked article - It should work just out of the box – no configuration needed in Global.asax or similar. Have you tried my exact sample code? The Sitecore routing is defined in a way so that you must include {id} parameter in the url. Also a namespace like [Sitecore.Services.Core.ServicesController("example1.test.andreas")] will result in urls like /sitecore/api/ssc/example1-test/andreas/{id}/{action}.

Comment: What data would you like to expose with this service?

Comment: Try to implement this approach instead https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2018/06/22/sitecore-and-webapi/ . Much straight forward has better control.

Comment: The disadvantage of that approach is that I have to implement pipelines and config files. I'd much rather use the other approach where things work "out of the box". I haven't tried your other suggestions yet, but will come back to you with results when I have.

Comment: @PeterProchazka It seems to be the naming convention that got me this time. I renamed my class to `CustomApiController`, and everything started working just fine. Thanks for the point in the right direction, and feel free to add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow MVC naming conventions for Controllers and rename your controller from `CustomApi` to `CustomApiController`.

Happy I could help you and that this did the trick.